# Problem with blazor server app with Azure AD authentication calling a secure Web API with a bearer token

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-server-side

I've created a web api which requires authorization and is deployed to an Azure Web App. I also have a Blazor Server app which requires Azure AD authentication.

When I run the Blazor Server app from within Visual Studio it can get a token and successfully call the web api deployed in Azure.

However, when I deploy the Blazor Server app to an Azure Web App it gets a 401 error when it calls the Web API, despite the fact that it worked from Visual Studio.

This is how I am setting the token prior to the Web API call

```
 var accessToken = await _authRepo.PrepareAuthenticatedClient();
            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
```

also including a catch of the exeception

```
@inject MicrosoftIdentityConsentAndConditionalAccessHandler ConsentHandler
```

```
  catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ConsentHandler.HandleException(ex);
            }
```

This procedure gets a token for the logged in user for the web api scope:

```
public async Task<string> PrepareAuthenticatedClient()
        {
            var accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new[] { _WPScope });
            return accessToken;

        }
```

This is the code in the startup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
                .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { "api://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/allaccess" })
                .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();



            services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));

            }).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
```

How do I set this up in Azure so that it works the way it does in Visual Studio?

Comment: Please show how you configured redirect url

Comment: Have tried the web app url /signin-oidc and also the web app url/.auth/login/aad/callback

Answer (score 0):

Please try these:

1. After decoding the token , if you see issuer url with v2 endpoint
   make sure to change accesstokenaccepted version to 2 in manifest in
   azure ad portal , if iss value has v1 endpoint change in manisfest
   to 1.
2. Also if above is not the cause, see if audience i.e; aud claim is equal to client id. Else try changing the scope by not including prefix api://.

And also please make sure the api permissions are granted consent.

Comment: Hi @kavyasaraboju-MT - not resolved yet - I've just looked at the manifest and the accesstokenaccepted seems to be "null" - so I'll try that first of all. The token being returned is v1

Comment: if iss is v1 endpoint having accesstokenaccepted version to 1 or null is fine. Please check if the api permissions for the exposed api in azure ad portal is granted consent .and please confirm if point 2 is also tried.